# Html resources status- from cache vs not modified - in google chrome DOM analyzer

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-chrome, browser

in google chrome, i go to an asp.net web site url after enabling the DOM inspector (F12). If I select the Network tab, I can see the resources requested along with their status, timeline etc. On subsequent requests, I see that the status for some items say '304 Not modified' and some say '(from cache)', including .js,.css and image files.

I was thinking that all css and images are cached, atleast if I request the page immediately. Are these two status messages the same, can someone explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the distinction is that a `304` indicates the browser sent a request and the *server* indicated the resource hadn't changed, whereas the `from cache` status may indicate that Chrome didn't even send a request--the browser knew to use the cache without ever contacting the server.

This could be verified with a tool like Fiddler to see whether `from cache` resources are ever requested.

Comment: thats what my initial thought was too, but there is really no difference between css file #1 and #2, so how come the browser sent the request for 1 and not 2. Is there anything specific that I need to do to the files to cache them specifically?

Comment: caching is largely controlled by the response headers, rather than the contents.  Have you inspected them to see if they differ?

Comment: Is there a response header per resource (css file, image etc). Sorry, I'm kind of new to these details. If so, how to set them, say for a image file?

Comment: yep; every resource (.js, .html, .jpg, etc) is retrieved by the browser using a single request and returned in a single response.  Headers are set by the webserver, and can be programmatically set by your application (but the specifics differ between languages, frameworks, and webservers)

Comment: Still does not explain why some of them are from cache and some are not. But i'll do some research on this. I'm using asp.net and I thought the browser cached all css files by default.

Comment: I used fiddler and verified that 304 indicates a round trip to server and from cache means no request was sent. Your answer is correct. Now I need to go figure out why its not being cached.

Comment: @coder net - did you ever figure this out? I'm just trying to understand the same thing. I've got two almost identical resources, javascript file in this case, neither which have been changed, and the browser seems to operate randomly. Thanks.